# ASP.NET MVC and Service Oriented Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, architecture

I would like to know how do i incorporate a feature like wcf within and MVC application. My current idea of the architecture is as follows:

> EntityFramework -> ASP.NET MVC (Views)
>
> EntityFramework -> ASP.NET MVC with
>   WCF endpoints -> mobile Apps.
>
> EntityFramework -> ASP.NET MVC ->
>   Silverlight (using .NET RIA Services).

So I'd have 1 asp.net mvc project. create my DAL in the models folder. have my controller access that DAL. Add a wcf file somewhere and have that call to the DAL. Some parts of the application i have a silverlight app that opens and uses the asp.net membership information and other related data.

Please correct me. I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your situation, I would do things a little differently.

I would create a seperate project for your Data Access Layer. I would also move business logic into a Business Logic Layer.

You could then share both your DAL and BLL between the ASP.NET MVC site (your Models would be a Facade to the BLL objects) and your WCF Services thus centralizing all of your logic into a central location.

Comment: Does this mean I will have no code in the controller and models folder?

Comment: It sounds like you are describing Domain Driven Design.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339725/Domain-Driven-Design-Clear-Your-Concepts-Before-Yo